# Programming in VBA the selection of multiple rows in a Word 2014 table

Tags: vba, ms-word, multipleselection

I want to change the font of all even rows in a large table in Microsoft Word (most versions, I use 2014) to red

I tried a simple loop :

```
For ii=2 to ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Count step 2
  ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(ii).Select
  Selection.Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
Next
```

This sometimes hangs, sometimes it works, but takes hours (my table has 14000 rows...)

Then I had the idea : Manually, I can select a row by left-clicking on its left, then add additional rows to the selection by Ctrl-left-click on their left.
And I can then modify the font of all rows selected at once.

So let's see if doing the same programmatically is faster ! I tried something like

```
 ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(2).Select
 For ii=4 to ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Count step 2
   Selection.Add (ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(ii))
 Next
 Selection.Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
```

but Add is not accepted as a valid Selection object member

Can someone help there ?

Comment: i don't know if this will make a difference ... replace the two lines of your code with `ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(ii).Font.ColorIndex = wdRed`

Answer (score 0):

define a *new style* and apply it to the table ... no vba needed

this is a macro recording of an example style change ... if you wish to use vba

```
Selection.Tables(1).Style = "Grid Table 5 Dark - Accent 2"
```

also, record a macro of doing a new style definition  .... lots of good stuff in it